# Question about the monotone convergence theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series

If every bounded monotonic sequence is convergent, does that mean that mean that every non-bounded non-monotonic sequence is divergent? Or can non-bounded non-monotonic sequences be convergent?

Comment: Are all convergent sequences bounded?

Comment: Yes, all [convergent sequences are bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113413/convergent-sequences-are-bounded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the proof of statement (1), obvious questions which are raised are answered in (2) and (3).

1) Every bounded monotonic sequence is convergent.

2) Every convergent real sequence is bounded (Proof : Exercise). However bounded sequence need not be convergent. For example : $(-1)^n$

3) Every convergent sequence need not be monotonic. For example : $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Monotonic sequence need not be convergent. For example : $n$

Comment: If the limit of the sequence is a finite number, can the sequence diverge?

Comment: If the limit is a finite nunber, the limit exists.

Comment: The sequence is not bounded, but when I take the limit of the sequence, it is a finite number

Comment: If the limit exists, can the sequence be divergent?

Comment: Your more general question is, I think, "If A and B implies C does not C  imply not A and not B".  NO!  What is true is that "not C implies not (A and B)" and "not (A and B)" is equivalent to "not A or not B".

Comment: Yes, that is generally what I am asking

Comment: Does bounded, monotonic,... etc apply to all or do they apply for n >= 1?

Comment: can horizontal asymptotes be considered bounds?